# Combine Columns in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe read into from an Excel file. I would like to combine all 4 "Value" columns and "Rental" Columns into a respective single column containing all values so that I have one Value and one Rental column.

Current dataframe is shown below.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.read_excel('HW2_Data.xlsx', sheet_name='Problem 4')
print(df)
```

[image]

Comment: It seems like it would be easier to make a scatter plot with my current knowledge

Comment: A scatter plot of what, exactly?

Comment: A scatterplot of the value of each house and the rental income that it generates.

The goal is to see if there is a relationship between house value and rental income

Comment: My apologies, I misread your original question. Please provide your data as [formatted copy-paste-able text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: Can you please also share the code you are using to read in this excel data?

Comment: No worries! updated.

Comment: Please provide your data as formatted copy-paste-able text, not as an image. Can you also provide an example of what's in the `Problem 4` sheet? It's not clear right now why your dataframe is turning out this way. Is the original data stored in two columns? I want to try to help you fix the problem with the source of your data before moving on to transforming your dataframe, if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `pd.wide_to_long`:

```
#Create dummy dataframe matching your column headers
df = pd.concat(
    [
        pd.DataFrame(
            {
                f"Value{i}": sorted(np.random.randint(75, 350, 12) * 1000),
                f"Rental{i}": sorted(np.random.randint(4370, 13000, 12)),
            }
        )
        for i in ["", ".1", ".2", ".3"]
    ],
    axis=1,
)

#Rename column headers to get consistent <word>.<number> format by adding .0 to first two columns
dfm = df.rename(columns=lambda x: x if '.' in x else x+'.0')

# Use pd.wide_to_long
df_out = pd.wide_to_long(dfm.reset_index(), ['Value', 'Rental'], 'index', 'No', '.', '\d')

df_out
```

Output:

```
          Value  Rental
index No                
0     0    89000    4492
1     0   151000    4799
2     0   175000    4849
3     0   187000    4853
4     0   254000    5301
5     0   271000    5590
6     0   279000    5860
7     0   297000    7653
8     0   297000   10308
9     0   299000   10604
10    0   330000   10695
11    0   337000   12167
0     1    87000    4482
1     1    91000    5598
2     1   145000    7225
3     1   157000    8105
4     1   185000    8558
5     1   192000    8700
6     1   193000    9109
7     1   215000    9437
8     1   250000   10963
9     1   260000   11362
10    1   276000   11895
11    1   338000   12079
0     2    84000    5141
1     2    92000    5198
2     2   107000    5646
3     2   136000    6417
4     2   143000    8548
5     2   200000    9338
6     2   225000    9679
7     2   245000    9997
8     2   327000   11787
9     2   328000   11829
10    2   328000   11889
11    2   334000   12438
0     3    81000    4652
1     3   112000    5129
2     3   143000    5648
3     3   153000    6412
4     3   178000    6629
5     3   188000    7463
6     3   239000    9382
7     3   240000    9594
8     3   263000   10505
9     3   265000   11633
10    3   296000   11835
11    3   314000   12416
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so I originally wanted to see if it was possible to prevent your data from being loaded in such an unfortunate format in the first place, but I've been waiting for an hour now and I'm ready for bed. Here's one way you could fix your issue which would not require looping:

```py
df = df.rename(columns={"Value": "Value.0", "Rental": "Rental.0"})
pd.wide_to_long(df.reset_index(), stubnames=["Value", "Rental"], i="index", j="drop", suffix=".\d+").reset_index().drop(["index", "drop"], axis=1)
```